# docker compose ignores that a service depends on another

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

Here's the current `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=my_app
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
  web:
    build: .
    image: my-app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    command: sh -c "python manage.py migrate && 
             python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    environment:
      - DB_USER=postgres
      - DB_PASSWORD=postgres
      - DB_HOST=db
      - DB_NAME=my_app
```

When I run the app for the first time, this happens:

```
% docker compose build && docker compose up
[+] Building 2.5s (10/10) FINISHED                                              
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                       0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 189B                                       0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 150B                                          0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.11.1-bullseye  2.0s
 => [1/5] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.11.1-bullseye@sha256:cc4910af48  0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                          0.2s
 => => transferring context: 1.21MB                                        0.2s
 => CACHED [2/5] COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt                    0.0s
 => CACHED [3/5] RUN pip install -r requirements.txt                       0.0s
 => CACHED [4/5] COPY . /app                                               0.0s
 => CACHED [5/5] WORKDIR /app                                              0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                     0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                    0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:d7b4a64b01b9de03dec4a0732eaf975b7bc68f1daefb4  0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/my-app                    0.0s

Use 'docker scan' to run Snyk tests against images to find vulnerabilities and learn how to fix them
[+] Running 3/3
 ⠿ Network my_app_default  Created                           0.2s
 ⠿ Container my_app-db-1   Created                           0.1s
 ⠿ Container my_app-web-1  Created                           0.2s
Attaching to my_app-db-1, my_app-web-1
my_app-db-1   | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
my_app-db-1   | This user must also own the server process.
my_app-db-1   | 
my_app-db-1   | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
my_app-db-1   | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
my_app-db-1   | The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
my_app-db-1   | 
my_app-db-1   | Data page checksums are disabled.
my_app-db-1   | 
my_app-db-1   | fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
my_app-db-1   | creating subdirectories ... ok
my_app-db-1   | selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
my_app-db-1   | selecting default max_connections ... 100
my_app-db-1   | selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
my_app-db-1   | selecting default time zone ... Etc/UTC
my_app-db-1   | creating configuration files ... ok
my_app-db-1   | running bootstrap script ... ok
my_app-db-1   | performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
my_app-db-1   | syncing data to disk ... ok
my_app-db-1   | 
my_app-db-1   | 
my_app-db-1   | Success. You can now start the database server using:
my_app-db-1   | 
my_app-db-1   |     pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start
my_app-db-1   | 
my_app-db-1   | initdb: warning: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
my_app-db-1   | initdb: hint: You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
my_app-web-1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
my_app-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 282, in ensure_connection
my_app-web-1  |     self.connect()
my_app-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
my_app-web-1  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
my_app-web-1  |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
my_app-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 263, in connect
my_app-web-1  |     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
my_app-web-1  |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
my_app-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
my_app-web-1  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
my_app-web-1  |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
my_app-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 215, in get_new_connection
my_app-web-1  |     connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
my_app-web-1  |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
my_app-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
my_app-web-1  |     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
my_app-web-1  |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
my_app-web-1  | psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
my_app-web-1  |     Is the server running on host "db" (172.24.0.2) and accepting
my_app-web-1  |     TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
my_app-web-1  | 
my_app-web-1  | 
my_app-web-1  | The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
my_app-web-1  | 
my_app-web-1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
my_app-web-1  |   File "/app/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
my_app-web-1  |     main()
my_app-web-1  |   File "/app/manage.py", line 18, in main
my_app-web-1  |     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
my_app-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
my_app-web-1  |     utility.execute()
my_app-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 440, in execute
my_app-web-1  |     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
my_app-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 402, in run_from_argv
my_app-web-1  |     self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
my_app-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 448, in execute
my_app-web-1  |     output = self.handle(*args, **options)
my_app-web-1  |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
my_app-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 96, in wrapped
my_app-web-1  |     res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
my_app-web-1  |           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
my_app-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 114, in handle
my_app-web-1  |     executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
my_app-web-1  |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
my_app-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
my_app-web-1  |     self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
my_app-web-1  |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
my_app-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 58, in __init__
my_app-web-1  |     self.build_graph()
my_app-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 235, in build_graph
my_app-web-1  |     self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
my_app-web-1  |                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
my_app-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 81, in applied_migrations
my_app-web-1  |     if self.has_table():
my_app-web-1  |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
my_app-db-1   | waiting for server to start....2023-01-08 12:43:30.440 UTC [47] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 15.1 (Debian 15.1-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
my_app-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 57, in has_table
my_app-web-1  |     with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
my_app-web-1  |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
my_app-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
my_app-web-1  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
my_app-web-1  |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
my_app-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 323, in cursor
my_app-web-1  |     return self._cursor()
my_app-web-1  |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
my_app-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 299, in _cursor
my_app-web-1  |     self.ensure_connection()
my_app-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
my_app-web-1  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
my_app-web-1  |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
my_app-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 281, in ensure_connection
my_app-web-1  |     with self.wrap_database_errors:
my_app-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
my_app-web-1  |     raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
my_app-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 282, in ensure_connection
my_app-web-1  |     self.connect()
my_app-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
my_app-web-1  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
my_app-web-1  |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
my_app-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 263, in connect
my_app-web-1  |     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
my_app-web-1  |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
my_app-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
my_app-web-1  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
my_app-web-1  |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
my_app-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 215, in get_new_connection
my_app-web-1  |     connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
my_app-web-1  |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
my_app-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
my_app-web-1  |     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
my_app-web-1  |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
my_app-db-1   | 2023-01-08 12:43:30.457 UTC [47] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
my_app-web-1  | django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
my_app-web-1  |     Is the server running on host "db" (172.24.0.2) and accepting
my_app-web-1  |     TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
my_app-web-1  | 
my_app-db-1   | 2023-01-08 12:43:30.476 UTC [50] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-01-08 12:43:29 UTC
my_app-db-1   | 2023-01-08 12:43:30.490 UTC [47] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
my_app-db-1   |  done
my_app-db-1   | server started
my_app-db-1   | CREATE DATABASE
my_app-db-1   | 
my_app-db-1   | 
my_app-db-1   | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*
my_app-db-1   | 
my_app-web-1 exited with code 1
my_app-db-1   | 2023-01-08 12:43:31.286 UTC [47] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
my_app-db-1   | waiting for server to shut down....2023-01-08 12:43:31.288 UTC [47] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
my_app-db-1   | 2023-01-08 12:43:31.319 UTC [47] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 53) exited with exit code 1
my_app-db-1   | 2023-01-08 12:43:31.320 UTC [48] LOG:  shutting down
my_app-db-1   | 2023-01-08 12:43:31.326 UTC [48] LOG:  checkpoint starting: shutdown immediate
my_app-db-1   | 2023-01-08 12:43:31.469 UTC [48] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 918 buffers (5.6%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=0.054 s, sync=0.076 s, total=0.149 s; sync files=250, longest=0.023 s, average=0.001 s; distance=4217 kB, estimate=4217 kB
my_app-db-1   | 2023-01-08 12:43:31.488 UTC [47] LOG:  database system is shut down
my_app-db-1   |  done
my_app-db-1   | server stopped
my_app-db-1   | 
my_app-db-1   | PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
my_app-db-1   | 
my_app-db-1   | 2023-01-08 12:43:31.692 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 15.1 (Debian 15.1-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
my_app-db-1   | 2023-01-08 12:43:31.695 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
my_app-db-1   | 2023-01-08 12:43:31.695 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
my_app-db-1   | 2023-01-08 12:43:31.701 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
my_app-db-1   | 2023-01-08 12:43:31.708 UTC [63] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-01-08 12:43:31 UTC
my_app-db-1   | 2023-01-08 12:43:31.720 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

It fails to connect to `db` because the service hasn't started yet depite being specified as a dependency. Here's the 2nd time:

```
% docker compose build && docker compose up
[+] Building 4.8s (11/11) FINISHED                                              
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                       0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                        0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 34B                                           0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.11.1-bullseye  4.2s
 => [auth] library/python:pull token for registry-1.docker.io              0.0s
 => [1/5] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.11.1-bullseye@sha256:cc4910af48  0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                          0.1s
 => => transferring context: 8.42kB                                        0.1s
 => CACHED [2/5] COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt                    0.0s
 => CACHED [3/5] RUN pip install -r requirements.txt                       0.0s
 => CACHED [4/5] COPY . /app                                               0.0s
 => CACHED [5/5] WORKDIR /app                                              0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                     0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                    0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:d7b4a64b01b9de03dec4a0732eaf975b7bc68f1daefb4  0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/my-app                    0.0s

Use 'docker scan' to run Snyk tests against images to find vulnerabilities and learn how to fix them
[+] Running 2/0
 ⠿ Container my_app-db-1   Created                           0.0s
 ⠿ Container my_app-web-1  Created                           0.0s
Attaching to my_app-db-1, my_app-web-1
my_app-db-1   | 
my_app-db-1   | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
my_app-db-1   | 
my_app-db-1   | 2023-01-08 12:48:54.148 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 15.1 (Debian 15.1-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
my_app-db-1   | 2023-01-08 12:48:54.152 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
my_app-db-1   | 2023-01-08 12:48:54.153 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
my_app-db-1   | 2023-01-08 12:48:54.157 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
my_app-db-1   | 2023-01-08 12:48:54.171 UTC [28] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-01-08 12:48:30 UTC
my_app-db-1   | 2023-01-08 12:48:54.187 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
my_app-web-1  | Operations to perform:
my_app-web-1  |   Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, core, sessions
my_app-web-1  | Running migrations:
my_app-web-1  |   Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
my_app-web-1  |   Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
my_app-web-1  |   Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
my_app-web-1  |   Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
my_app-web-1  |   Applying admin.0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices... OK
my_app-web-1  |   Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
my_app-web-1  |   Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
my_app-web-1  |   Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
my_app-web-1  |   Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
my_app-web-1  |   Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
my_app-web-1  |   Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
my_app-web-1  |   Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
my_app-web-1  |   Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK
my_app-web-1  |   Applying auth.0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length... OK
my_app-web-1  |   Applying auth.0010_alter_group_name_max_length... OK
my_app-web-1  |   Applying auth.0011_update_proxy_permissions... OK
my_app-web-1  |   Applying auth.0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length... OK
my_app-web-1  |   Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
my_app-web-1  | Watching for file changes with StatReloader
my_app-web-1  | Performing system checks...
my_app-web-1  | 
my_app-web-1  | System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
my_app-web-1  | January 08, 2023 - 12:49:01
my_app-web-1  | Django version 4.1.5, using settings 'my_app.settings'
my_app-web-1  | Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
my_app-web-1  | Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

It runs as it should've had in the first time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [docker compose documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#depends_on), `depends_on` it does not wait until the service is ready, only that it has started. In my experience starting a postgres container usually takes a few seconds and since you need to wait until postgres is ready to recieve connections, it is recommended to use some form of [control startup](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/).

You could use the example Docker provides or do this yourself in Django, [here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64136820/django-docker-compose-retry-database-connection-when-django-db-utils-operation) from a similar stackoverflow thread.

Comment: The whole point of having a startup order is to avoid these kinds of issues. I don't understand the difference between this and not specifying it as a dependency at all. Both lead to the same result, which makes it pretty useless.

Comment: I agree, it is mostly useless since the only thing you can be sure of using `depends_on` is that the service will get initiated first, not that it's ready. Only thing I can maybe think of is that it's a bit more explicit for people to read... maybe